# AnimatedContainer with rounded corners

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I have been trying to make rounded corners in an `AnimatedContainer`. So I wrote this code :

```
 return Center (
    child: Column (
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget> [
        AnimatedContainer (
          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
          color: Colors.white,
          height: _isContainerVisible ? 500.0 : 0.0,
          width: _isContainerVisible ? 300.0 : 0.0,
          decoration: BoxDecoration (
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0)
          ),
        )
      ]
    )
  );
```

for some reason I cannot make the corner rounded. Also I am getting an error message for this. Is there a way to make the corners rounded?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You missed

```
border: Border.all(color: Colors.blue)
```

Also delete `color` from `AnimatedContainer` and add that in `decoration`

Complete solution

```
return Center(
  child: Column(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    children: <Widget>[
      AnimatedContainer(
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
        height: 300,
        width: 300,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white, // added
          border: Border.all(color: Colors.orange, width: 5), // added
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

Comment: I have a problem, only the borders are blue and the inside is transparent. How can I fix this?

Comment: Thank you so much!